# Centering icon in custom checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

So I had to write my own checkbox due to the limitations the existing one has, I needed 3 states with a bit of logic in it.

I am trying to get the icon centered in the container with no success, it only centers when I use the optimal size I guess for the IconButton which is 45, and that IconButton is too large for my needs. here is the code :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 25,
      width: 25,
      color: widget.status == Constants.Rejected
          ? Colors.red
          : widget.status == Constants.Done ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: widget.status == Constants.Rejected
            ? Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            : widget.status == Constants.Done
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                : Container(),
        onPressed: _changeState,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here is the result :

[image: Resulted checkboxes]

This is how it outcomes when I use height and width of 45:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I can't test right now but check if setting Icon size to 25 it works

Comment: @JoãoPedroAcheVirgili Nope, it doesn't. If i make it really small - like 12 it does center but that just looks bad and probably won't be responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),`
into IconButton

or use GestureDetector with child Icon instead og Button because Button has paddings

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 25,
      width: 25,
      color: widget.status == Constants.Rejected
          ? Colors.red
          : widget.status == Constants.Done ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        child: widget.status == Constants.Rejected
            ? Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white)
            : widget.status == Constants.Done ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white) : Container(),
        onTap: (){
          // 
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

as for me, GestureDetector is a better option because it hasn't Splash animation like button

Comment: Thanks alot. Problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)` in `IconButton` widget

> just because of by default set padding so you need to remove that
>   padding

```
Container(
        height: 25,
        width: 25,
        color: Colors.red,
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), // here is set 0 padding
            icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {},

        ));
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks alot.